# How to use a php variable with xsl?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, function, namespaces

How would I use an auto incremented php variable in XSL?

XSL?

```
function xslt_string($key){
$key++;
return isset($saved[$key]) ? $saved[$key] : '';
}
```

In XML?

```
<xsl:variable name="phpstring" 
select="php:function('xslt_string', string('$saved[$key]'))" />
<xsl:value-of select="$post_param" />
```

XML NAME SPACE?

```
xmlns:php="/". (function on page that parses XSL)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do it this way:

In your XSL:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$myVar"/>
```

In your PHP:

```
$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
//...
$proc->setParameter('', 'myVar', 'Your value here');
```

See [XSLTProcessor::setParameter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.setparameter.php) for more info.

Comment: Great but this value keeps changing (incrementing) so how would I add that to the code?